# $2^nn!\le n^n$ for $n\ge6$

Tags: inequality, factorial

Guys I just can't solve this one. Really need some help with it.

> Show that this inequality holds true:
>
> 1. $2^nn!\le n^n$ for all $n\ge6$
> 2. $n^n\le3^nn!$ for all $n\ge1$

Comment: Do you know mathematical induction?

Comment: yes I do, it worked for N=1 but had hudge problems with n+1 to find my Induction hypothesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Induction usually helps, for the first one, $n=6$ gives 
$$2^6\cdot 6! = 46080 \le 6^6=46656$$
so the base case is done, assume it is true for $n$, then for $n+1$ we have
$$2^{n+1}(n+1)! = 2^n n! \cdot2(n+1)\leq n^n\cdot2(n+1)=2n^{n+1}+2n^n < (n+1)^{n+1}$$
where hte last inequality comes from binomial theorem, you can do similarly for the last one.

Comment: Could you elaborate how the binomial theorem verifies the last inequality?  When I expand $(n+1)^{n+1}$, I get $n^{n+1}+(n+1)n^n+\cdots=2n^{n+1}+n^n+\cdots$, not $2n^{n+1}+2n^n$.  How many more terms are needed?

Comment: It doesn't need to equal it, just be greater which it is because the third term of $(n+1)^{n+1}$ will be $n^n\cdot \frac{(n+1)(n)(n-1)/2!}$

Comment: I don't think that's the right third term.  In any event, it would be easier to remove a $n+1$ from each side and show $2n^n\le(n+1)^n=n^n+n\cdot n^{n-1}+\cdots$.

Comment: Whoopsie, yeah you rae correct, I got a bit lazy in my thought!

Comment: Is it even necessairy to get the third term, because we can see our Induction Hypothesis in the middle term?

Comment: Not really, just being pedantic!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$ is an increasing function of limit $e$ (and $2<e<3$)

If you can show that, then inductions are easy.